# Firebase (Android) : after first time email registration in Firebase, how to go to login activity instead of register activity?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have an app where first activity lists four users names. On clicking each users name, another activity opens where the user can register for the first time. After registration, lets consider that the user kills the app. The user id would have been created in firebase. When user opens the app again and clicks on his/her name in the first activity, he/she should be taken directly to the login page and not the register page. How do I make the app learn that this particular user has already registered and should be taken to login page? Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After registeration, set a flag in SharedPreferences saying registered and next time when the user comes to FirstActivity check whether the flag is true or not. If true take him to the Login Page,if not take to Registeration Page.

```
 pref.edit().putBoolean("registered", true).commit();
```

Comment: Thank you! I already tried tried implementing shared pref but in a wrong way. Now all ok!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences.html), there you can learn how `SharedPreferences` works.

Comment: Thank you! I already tried tried implementing shared pref but in a wrong way. Now all ok!